# REACT fetch properties from nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I am using react to render data from properties in a *json* that is *nested*. I don't have a problem rendering the properties that are not nested such as `'name'`, and `'id'`, but when it comes to grabbing a nested prop such as `place:location{...}` etc, it says `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"`

My json format looks as follows:

```
data = [ {
  "end_time": "2015-03-28T21:00:00-0700",
  "name": "Brkn Intl. Bay Area Season 2!",
  "place": {
    "name": "MVMNT Studio",
    "location": {
      "city": "Berkeley",
      "country": "United States",
      "latitude": 37.85381,
      "longitude": -122.27875,
      "state": "CA",
      "street": "2973 Sacramento St",
      "zip": "94702"
    },
    "id": "459771574082879"
  },
  "start_time": "2015-03-28T15:00:00-0700" }, ...]
```

This is my react code:

```
  class ResultBox extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    posts: []
     };
  }
   componentDidMount() {
   axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/events')
     .then(res => {
     let posts = res.data.map(obj => obj);
     this.setState({posts});
     console.log(posts);
    });

 }
  render() {
   return (
      this.state.posts.map(function(events){
        return <div className='result_box'>

       <p>{events.name}</p>
       <p>{events.place.location.city}</p> <----- This give me error!!!
       </div>
     })

  );
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!!

Comment: Could you `console.log(events)` before returning the new div and check whether it has `events` or not?

Comment: One of your `place` should be undefined in the `json`. You can print all the json and check it.

Comment: Seems like you have problem with data, not with code. Add validation step and you will see where the problem comes from

Comment: When I console.log(events) it returns each dictionary in the list. So do you guys think its because some of my data does not have a place/location prop?

Comment: Yes, it seem like some of the data does not contain a place prop.

Comment: You need to wrap your rendered HTML by a tag.

Comment: Anyone know how I can bypass dictionaries that do not have a Place property?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like not all `events` have property `place` defined. 
You can either warn about it on every component or just ignore and prevent `undefined` values to be rendered:

```
this.state.posts.map(events =>
  <div key={events.id} className='result_box'>
    <p>{events.name}</p>
    {events.place && <p>{events.place.location.city}</p>}
  </div>
)
```

Lodash's [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) method also can help you with this:

```
<p>{get(events, 'place.location.city', '')}</p>
```

Comment: @kpo1 Don't forget to add `key` prop to each `div` within `map`. This is really important so React knows which components have been added, removed or even modified :)